# Hiding the latitude and longitude in a Google Map

Tags: php, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I am working on a Google Map that shows a spot on the map that supposed to stay secret for users. So my question is how to hide the lat and lng in my Google map. 
Users shouldn't see the lat and lng in the page source code, because it would spoil the secret. It's an absolute secret. 
Currently i'm using Google maps static api (image maps) in combination with php.

I'm wondering how I could hide these values in a safe way. Waterproof as can be.

Thanks in advance.

edit: this is the code I use for the static map image.

```
<img border="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=&zoom=<?php echo $zoomLevel;?>&size=246x179&markers=color:Red%3Clabel:A%7C52.138433,5.218506&sensor=false" />
```

so the 52.138433 and 5.218506 are the values that I want to hide for public.

Comment: Ah yes I posted the code for the google map static img.

Comment: Is the lat/lon showing up on the image, the source, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the nature of html and the fact that the static maps API requires you to point your image to a url, you can not really hide this from someone who is looking at your source code.

Comment: is it possible if I use the javascript version of maps api?

Comment: So what would you recommend for hiding the lat and lng but still be able to display a google map? flash?

Comment: Maybe you could have a map without it and then whenever the user does an action of some sort you fire off a php script that changes your html.  I don't know your project so I'm just guessing in the dark.

Comment: Its a gmap that zooms in every time a user tweets a certain hashtag. the marker represents the prize that users can win if they tweet enough. So overtime, the map will zoom in, so that the actual place will be clear. Untill that time, the map lat and lng has to stay secret. So that's why I want to hide it for public.

Comment: I'll dig around and see if we can't find some novel solution.